# Get multiples row values in single row as a list or array in mysql

Tags: mysql

When i run the query:

```
select * from table where UserID='21';
```

My sql result shows as below:

```
UserID FName  LName  StatusID  Company   Notes 
21     Sam    Jones  21        AT&T      Applied
21     Sam    Jones  32        Verizon   In Process
21     Sam    Jones  36        T-Mobile  Applied
```

Is there a way for me to get the result in the following manner ?

```
UserID FName  LName  StatusID   Company                 Notes
21     Sam    Jones  [21,32,36] [AT&T,Verizon,T-mobile] [Applied,In Process,Applied]
```

Any tips in the right direction would be of great help too.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a data table I have try this for your's

[image]

[image]